# Efficiently returning objects joining ALL tags

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a basic tagging-style system and am wondering how efficient my queries are.

My specific use case involves tagging `recipe` objects with `ingredients` through a `requirement` object, which has a `recipe_id` and an `ingredient_id`.

Recipes, ingredients and requirements are all completely siloed by `user`.

I want to be able to return a user's recipes that include ALL ingredients in a given set.

The way I'm doing this, given a list of `ingredient_ids` **(1,2)** and `user_id` of **1**, is like this:

```
SELECT `recipes`.* FROM `recipes` 
  WHERE `recipes`.`id` IN (
    SELECT `requirements`.`recipe_id` 
      FROM `requirements` 
      WHERE `requirements`.`ingredient_id` IN (1, 2) 
       AND `requirements`.`user_id` = 1
      GROUP BY `requirements`.`recipe_id` 
      HAVING COUNT(`requirements`.`recipe_id`) = 2)
```

This is returning the data I need but I'm worried about its performance. The sub-query doesn't look good because it is grabbing all requirements with ingredient_id 1 or 2, grouping them by recipe and then counting them to match the given array size, simply to create an array against which to further query recipe ids.

But the `requirements` table could be massive, as each entry manages one of potentially an n-squared number of bi-directional relationships between recipes and ingredients. So it doesn't make sense to me to query the whole table in this way.

Am I missing something?

I've often heard that IN and NULL equality comparisons are so much faster than JOINs, but surely not when the complexity of the subquery negates the speed saving?

It seems like a very simple problem that I'm over-engineering, how would you improve it?

Comment: Have you actually experienced any performance problems?  How large are the tables?

Comment: I haven't launched yet but I'm interested in the performance even for the sake of understanding how this kind of query works under the hood and how it could be made more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your database to test, sorry, So I am not sure if this will yield the result you want. But maybe try join to the `requirements` table instead of using a subquery, it will avoid the potential performance loss and just make for generally cleaner code. Here is what I hope will work for you:

```
SELECT `recipes`.`recipe_id`
FROM `recipes` AS rec
JOIN `requirements` AS req ON rec.`recipe_id` = req.`recipe_id`
WHERE `requirements`.`ingredient_id` IN (1, 2) 
AND `requirements`.`user_id` = 1
GROUP BY `recipes`.`recipe_id` 
HAVING COUNT(`requirements`.`ingredient_id`) = 2
```

If you have questions let me know